# ¿Como puedo en Odoo 11 ocultar campos solo al crear y editar un formulario?

Tags: odoo

Tengo creadas las vistas de tipo Tree y de tipo Form para un pequeño módulo de Odoo 11 que estoy creando. Pero hay un campo, llamémoslo campoX que me interesa solo que no se vea cuando accedo a los detalles del sujeto:persona, barco, planta, o lo que sea. Siendo que solo aparezca tal campo cuando se edite o cree un nuevo sujeto.

He visto el atributo invisible para la vista y para el modelo, pero no es exactamente lo que necesito, pues hace que siempre oculte el campoX.

¿Podría alguien poner un ejemplo genérico? Debe ser algo sencillo, pero después de buscar no encuentro algo que me sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Debes añadir la clase 'oe_edit_only' en el campo al mostrarlo en la vista:

```
<field name="campoX" class="oe_edit_only"/>
```